# Un solo commit para varios proyectos?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, git, bitbucket

Me encuentro con el siguiente problema:

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación de ventas personalizada en flutter para varios clientes, de forma que la mayor parte de los ficheros del proyecto será común para todos los clientes y otros serán personalizados.

Mi intención es tener para cada cliente un repositorio diferente listo para clonar y ejecutar, para poder generar apk y listo. Pero al momento de mantener la aplicación y añadir mejoras, me gustaría que los ficheros comunes se actualizaran automáticamente en todos los repositorios. De forma que hiciera un commit para varios proyectos.

Tengo el repositorio en bitbucket y acostumbro a subir los cambios desde el mismo Android Studio. Hay alguna forma de poder hacerlo?

Si no se entiende lo suficiente o faltan detalles comentar y editaré la pregunta.

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) gracias por ayudar a esta comunidad. pero debes ser mas especifico, muéstranos que has intentado, dale un vistazo al siguiente contenido [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que cambiar la estructura de tus repositorios.

### Opción 1:

Monorepo con *Android flavors*:

En esta opción todas las aplicaciones están en **un mismo** repositorio. Puedes generar APKs distintos para cada cliente usando los [Android Build Variants](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants). Los variants son muy comunes y fáciles de usar.

### Opción 2

Múltiples apps con un repo como *submodule*

Esto se parece a lo que expones. Tienes que extraer el código común a un único repo; en los repos de cada app añades dicho repo común como un submódulo. A la hora de hacer *commit*, los cambios de la aplicación de cliente irán al repo que toca, y los cambios en el código común irán al repo común.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Lo que NO deberías hacer es tener código duplicado en todos los repositorios e intentar sincronizarlo. La solución es buscar la manera de tener dicho código común en un solo sitio.

Comment: La opción 1 esta muy bien y es fácil de usar, pero no me sirve para publicar en iOS. Tendría que hacer Build Variants para Android y Templates para iOS. Demasiado trabajo.
La segunda opción según mi punto de vista es la mejor, gracias por la ayuda!!